# When should one use MOVS opposed to MOV in x86 Assembly?

Tags: assembly, optimization, x86, mov

I've come across both of these instructions in the [The Intel 64 and 32 Bit Architectures Software Developer Manual](http://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/manuals/64-ia-32-architectures-software-developer-manual-325462.pdf), and am simply wondering what the differences between the two are, and when I should use one of them over the other.

Comment: The MOVS instruction performs arbitrarily sized memory-to-memory copies. The MOV instruction performs 8, 16, 32 or 64 bit register-to-register, register-to-memory or memory-to-register copies.

Comment: [This might be a better reference](http://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/manuals/64-ia-32-architectures-software-developer-instruction-set-reference-manual-325383.pdf) for you (see chapter 3).

Comment: Once you know what `mov` and `movs` do, (and because you've read about them in the Intel manual you do know **what** they do), the question about **when** becomes borderline opinion-based.

Answer (score 3):

The `MOVS` instruction is generally intended to be used more than once since it automatically increments or decrements the values of `edi` and `esi`. Increment or decrement depends on if the Direction flag is clear or set, respectively. This can be used with the `REP` prefix to make it repeat by decrementing `ecx` until it hits zero.

According to some documentation that I read, the history of the `movs` instruction was to move strings one byte at a time, though you can have it move larger items (words and quadwords, specifically). It will automatically change `edi` and `esi` by the correct amount, but it will still only decrement `ecx` by one, so be careful if you are moving unicode strings, for example.

The page at http://x86.renejeschke.de/html/file_module_x86_id_279.html explains the exact conditions for the `rep` prefix and its variants.